# In a large Visual Studio solution, how can I quickly identify the projects with build events?

Tags: visual-studio, projects-and-solutions, solution, build-events

I have a fairly large Visual Studio solution (> 30 projects). Every time I start a debugging session, the whole solution is recompiled. I vaguely remember that one of the projects has some `xcopy` post-build event, and I know from past experience that this can trigger solution recompilations even when not necessary. So I would like to remove that build event and replace it with a different mechanism.

Unfortunately I cannot remember exactly *which* project has the build event, and I would like to avoid having to manually open each project's *Properties* pages and look for a build event.

Is there an automated way for identifying all the projects in a solution that have some build event defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following regular expression in Find In Files to search all the csproj/vbproj files inside your solution directory for `PreBuildEvent` or `PostBuildEvent` which isn't followed by a newline character (assuming you didn't put a line break at the start of the build event textbox). Don't forget to tick the "Use Regular Expressions" checkbox:

```
(Pre|Post)BuildEvent\>[^\r]
```

Here is what my Find In Files dialog looks like:

[image]